# HP Quality Center Python Tests not executing any lines of script

Tags: python-2.7, hp-quality-center

I am familiar with Selenium using C# and integrating it with TeamCity - as a background.  I am at a new company now.  We have HP Quality Center and I saw a few articles how to use QC, Selenium, and Python Script to automate tests.  I am having a major issue even getting a basic TDOutput.Print("test") to show up in the output log, unless I am wrong in expecting any TDOutput.Print lines to show up in that space.

I have a Windows 7 box.

The steps I have followed are:

- installed Python on my machine (2.7)
- installed steuptools
- installed pip I can install items using pip on the command line, including
  selenium In QC
- I create a new VAPI-XP test
- Choose PythonScript in the Wizard
- Then click Finish (and do not go any further on the wizard)
- Quality Center will then generate a skeleton script.
- In the skeleton, Under TDOutput.Clear(), I type: TDOutput.Print("Hello
  World")
- The output window never clears and it never prints "Hello
  World"
- This is what I see in output window: Test is completed

Any suggestions on what easy step I have missed?  I obviously do not have a lot of experience with this tool so its hard for me to see why I can't even get a print statement to execute - let alone worry about the selenium portion of my testing.

Answer (score 1):

I found an article by fijiaaron that let me know even if you/I have a 64 bit machine, we need the 32 bit version of Python installed, as soon as I installed the 32 bit version, I was able to see the print lines.  Now on to the selenium...